# Efficiently calling a Python function

Tags: c++, python, scripting, boost, embed

I'm embedding Python into my game. The scripts will be used to define the character AI, how entities react to game events, etc — this means there's going to be a script for every type of entity in the game.

Each script will have a function like `createEntity()` or something which will return the constructed entity. What would be an efficient(ish) way of calling these functions (remember, there's one in every entity's script).

My initial thought was to do something like what you see below, however, I'm unsure as to how efficient this is. For example, what happens with the imported hero module after I run that string? Does it remain loaded in the main module? If that's the case, that's problematic since I'm going to be importing lots of scripts for all the entities I might need to add to the game world.

```
boost::python::handle<> result(
    PyRun_String("import hero\n"    "createEntity()\n",
        Py_file_input, main_namespace.ptr(), main_namespace.ptr())
);

// Then extract the entity from `result`...
```

What suggestions do you have?

Comment: Without more detail, I suggest you may be doing it backwards. If you want to define behavior in Python then write the application in Python calling into C++ for the machine-dependent, fast-path activities. Embedding Python in the manner you suggest plays to the faults of both languages, inverting it plays to their strengths.

Comment: @msw Up until now I imagined the end result should be an executable (written in C++) that calls functions defined in Python whenever it needs to. Is my image wrong?

Comment: You can do it either way -- there are Python games that call C and programs that embed Python.

Comment: To call a function in a module, you have to import the module. To import a module, you have to run it (due to the dynamicness of Python, also because that's the way all Python implementations do it and you *don't* want to build your own half-assed incompatible implementation). There's no way around importing the modules. What are you expecting?

Comment: Honestly, if you're making an embedded scripting language for a game, perhaps JavaScript or Lua would be a better choice than Python. They are designed specifically for embedding, whereas Python tends to want to be run from the interpreter and load modules. They both make it easy to create sandboxed environments. They're just more natural fits for the problems you are trying to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not specify whether space efficiency (i.e. memory), time efficiency, or labor efficiency is most important to you.  Merely because you are considering a hybrid C++ / Python application, I assume that labor efficiency is a significant factor.  Because you are developing a game, I assume that there will be some part of it that has a need for extremely tight execution speed.

Perhaps this approach will strike a balance.  Make all the user interaction (input and output, including any networking) C++ based for minimum latency.  You might place this in its own thread or process.  Given a high level event from the model, like a character moving, this code very quickly updates the screen and the network.  Given a user event, or an event from the network, it sends a message to the model.

The game model, which can be asynchronous to the view/control, would then be in Python for your convenience and so you can take advantage of functional programming etc.  You could use shared memory or a similar IPC mechanism between the two and start them separately if actually embedding an interpreter is inconvenient.

While certain AI applications are CPU-intensive, and therefore it may be tempting to go back to C or C++ for them, I would advise doing that as a final step, in response to clear responsiveness issues in interpreted code, if you do it at all.  You may even want to follow this line of thought with the graphics also, since nowadays most graphics processing is delegated to the video hardware, if you have a way to make the library calls you need from Python code.

Though I am not a game developer, I have been around and I have seen few situations in which the (nowadays) microseconds difference between single equivalent C and Python operations is perceptible to users.  Perceptible performance problems are nearly always due to other factors, such as disk I/O, network latency or inefficient algorithm implementations.

Comment: Based on the questioner's other posts, it appears as if he may be attempting to generate compiled binary first and foremost. I've seen this sort of question pop-up when someone assumes that a binary distribution will be harder to hack; such questions always presume far less motivation than game hackers seem to exhibit.

Comment: @msw You're thinking way too far ahead (and making way too many assumptions). I just want the executable to read Python scripts; security is at the very bottom of my concerns -- if they want to modify my game, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

[Ousterhout on the role of scripting languages](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/scripting.html) is an oldie but goodie. In the case of a game where you have said that the gameplay is to be scripted, the model (Python) is already organizing the flow as you have described it. If PyGame or similar library isn't up to the task of presenting the view, find or build a Python module that can.

Put another way, when I suggested you've got the integration backwards, it sounds like you are asking the view to call the model repeatedly to update itself. I cannot think of a way that putting the metaphoric cart before the horse will yield either efficiency or ease of development.

Comment: Doesn't it all depend on exactly what you want the end result to be? I don't want to write a game in Python; I want to write a game in C++ that can be scripted. In other words, the "main thing" is the C++ executable, not the Python scripts.

Comment: @Paul the two aren't mutually exclusive... you could always have your C++ executable launch a Python script that then calls back to the C++ executable.

Comment: "I don't want to write a game in Python". Okay, so don't. Nevertheless, you should understand your design choice. "Because that's what I want" is certainly a sufficient answer although not as satisfying as "Because approach X is better than Y".

Comment: It's important to note that Ousterhout's document only covers command-line interpreted scripting languages. Scripting languages that are designed for embedding (Lua, JavaScript) are not touched. The problem domain he is referring to (tying multiple applications together) is not the problem domain that the person asking the question is dealing with. Embedded scripting languages solve a different problem from shell scripts like Python and Perl.

Comment: Re: Nicol Bolas: I disagree with you assessment.  Ousterhout is also the creator of TCL, which was always intended as an embedded scripting language.  The real advantage of this approach is that it does not *dictate* a means by which the integration works.  Consider javascript in the browser, which can integrate features provided by the browser with external javascript libraries and with features from browser plugins.  It's not the *browser* that defines rich internet applications, it's merely an interpreter for applications written mainly in javascript.